# Django Channels 2 websockets multiple AuthMiddlewareStacks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

Trying to make some app using websockets with django channels.
I have 2 websocket clients - one is a web interface/js app, other - python application. I want a different authorization requirements for them (their consumers) (preferably a way to use AuthMiddlewareStacks)

How can i implement this? can't find an answer in the doc https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/routing.html

Here is a 'sketch'. (`routing.py` not gonna work this way).
I use DRF, DRF-JWT, django channels 2, if it's relevant.

**appmain.routing.py**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            app.routing.websocket_cli_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
    "websocket_0": TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            app.routing.websocket_web_urlpatterns
        ]),
    )
})
```

**app.routing.py**

```
websocket_cli_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/app/<str:var1>/<str:var2>/', consumers.CliConsumer),
]

websocket_web_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/app/<str:var1>/', consumers.WebConsumer),
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: I faced the same. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not really. I end up handling authorization within a websocket consumer (partially)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own auth handler that combines the logic from the auth handlers you want to use. (You can just call both their **call** methods and only fail if both fail.) Process the token out of a GET parameter or http header so the URLs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
# middleware.py
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

import jwt
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import jwt_decode_handler, jwt_get_username_from_payload


class JWTAuthMiddleware():
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        query_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(scope["query_string"].decode()).items()}

        jwt_value = query_dict.get('token', None)
        if jwt_value:
            try:
                try:
                    payload = jwt_decode_handler(jwt_value)
                except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
                    msg = _('Signature has expired.')
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
                except jwt.DecodeError:
                    msg = _('Error decoding signature.')
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
                except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed()

                scope['user'] = self.authenticate_credentials(payload)

            except exceptions.AuthenticationFailed:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        return self.inner(scope)

    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        """
        Returns an active user that matches the payload's user id and email.
        """
        User = get_user_model()
        username = jwt_get_username_from_payload(payload)

        if not username:
            msg = _('Invalid payload.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            msg = _('Invalid signature.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        if not user.is_active:
            msg = _('User account is disabled.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        close_old_connections()
        return user


JWTAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: JWTAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))



#routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from core.middleware import JWTAuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'websocket':
            JWTAuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(apps.myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
            )

    })
```

Comment: what is it about? maybe you didn't read the question carefully

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
# consumers.py

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

class PrinterWSAuthMiddleWare:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        close_old_connections()

        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        if b'authorization' in headers:
            try:
                token_name, token_key = headers[b'authorization'].decode().split()
                if token_name == 'bearer':
                    printer = Printer.objects.select_related('user').get(auth_token=token_key)
                    scope['user'] = printer
                else:
                    scope['user'] = None
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                scope['user'] = None
        return self.inner(scope)

TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: PrinterWSAuthMiddleWare(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

```
# routing.py

...
    'websocket': TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            api.ws_routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
...
```

It is not documented but the `AuthMiddlewareStack` checks cookies and session behind the scene and set the scope if any of them is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it working only after changing signature of `__call__` method in custom middleware to async:

```
class JwtAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Do custom auth
        return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)


    def JwtAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
        return JwtAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```